# Generate log transformation of all continuous variables in Stata + interactions

Tags: statistics, stata

I'm attempting to write a `foreach` loop in Stata that will automatically generate log transformations of all continuous variables in the dataset (exclude strings, binary variables). The code I have tried, which doesn't seem to work is as follows:

```
qui foreach v of varlist _all {
    gen 'v' = log(v)
}
```

Additionally I would like to write a loop that will generate all possible permutations of interaction terms, but am not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several problems:

1. If you use `_all` and have string type variables, then the loop will fail. You cannot take the log of a string variable. That will result in type mismatch error, so use `ds` to recover the list of variables that are numeric.
2. You have `gen 'v'` and it should be `` gen `v' ``. Notice the subtle difference in the type of quote used.
3. You cannot `generate` a variable that already exists. So append, for example, the prefix `l` to the new variable names: `` gen l`v' ``.
4. You are missing the quotes in `` log(`v') ``.

Try something more like

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto

ds, has(type numeric) 

quietly foreach v of varlist `r(varlist)' {
    gen l`v' = log(`v')
}
```

This won't guard you against taking the log of indicator variables (like `foreign` in the example) or non-positive values (which will result in missings (`.`).

If we assume that variables with value labels (`help label`) are non-continuous variables, then you could filter the variable list further:

```
<snip>

ds, has(type numeric) 
ds `r(varlist)', not(vallabel)

<snip>
```

This code will leave out the indicator variable `foreign`.

See `help return` to read on using stored results like `r(varlist)`.

Comment: Assuming continuous variables have non-negative values, the safe approach is to use `gen l`v'=log(`v'+1)`.

Comment: Thanks @Metrics. That should read ``gen l`v'=log(`v'+1)``. I've assumed the original poster will correctly handle the mathematics of his problem. For completeness, Stata will produce a missing (`.`) if it is instructed to take the log of a non-positive number.

Comment: @Metrics log(x + 1) is not something to do routinely without waving a big flag that you are doing it. It's a common trick in some areas, but regarded as an unjustifiable fudge in many others.

Comment: Great thanks for all the feedback on the log transformation loop. I'll have a crack at running the code and will report back if any problems. Any idea on how to interact all numeric variables with a loop?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2009-09/msg00449.html

Comment: Check out `tuples` from SSC.